# Bitbucket Pipeline failing with ERROR: Python 2 is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, maven, bitbucket-pipelines

After running OK for months, my pipeline build is failing.

I think I need a new docker image that has java 8, maven, plus python 3 but cannot find one. Would prefer not to have to create and post a custom image myself.

Error:

```
[INFO] Detected App Engine appengine-web.xml based application.
Apr 20, 2023 7:51:41 AM com.google.cloud.tools.managedcloudsdk.install.Downloader download
INFO: Downloading https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz 
to /root/.cache/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/downloads/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
Welcome to the Google Cloud CLI!
WARNING: You appear to be running this script as root. This may cause
the installation to be inaccessible to users other than the root user.
ERROR: Python 2 is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK. Please use Python version 3.5 and up.
If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.
```

Pipeline excerpt:

```
      - step:
          name: Build, stage App Engine content
          caches:
            - maven
          image: maven:3.8.1-openjdk-8
          deployment: production
          script:
            - mvn -D skipTests=true -P useJfrog --settings settings.xml install appengine:stage
            - pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:1.1.1
```